# Gboard (and Google Translate): outputting translation in different destination scripts

Tags: languages, gboard, google-translate

I am using Gboard to translate text from English to other languages. Some languages can be written in more than one script.

I was wondering whether it would be possible to select Bosnian in Cyrillic rather than Latin script as my translation output, or pinyin instead of hanzi as the output text for Chinese.

The same goes for other languages that can have more than one destination translation output script.

Is this possible with Gboard (and, in general, also with Google Translate)? How can I achieve this behavior?